# How to export Quartz Composer/Origami composition to QuickTime as an animation?

Tags: quartz-composer, prototyping, interaction-design

I use Facebook Origami plugin and everything works well in the viewer – you have to click to see the animation.

But when I try to export the composition to .mov it generates a clip filled with a static image. How to "record" the interaction to make the animation visible?

Comment: Hi, you can use QuickTime's screen recording to solve your problem. See this answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/VNDMY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to "record" your mouse movements and then play them back for recording. You can do this either using a few Queue patches or via JavaScript. Record your interaction and then play it back when recording your movie.

Here's what it could look like in JavaScript:

```
var _values = []
var _index = 0

function (__number outputX, __number outputY, __boolean outputLeft) main (__number inputX, __number inputY, __boolean inputLeft, __boolean record, __boolean recordReset, __boolean play, __boolean playReset, __boolean resetValues, __number patchTime)
{
    var result = new Object();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var left = false;

    if (record) {
        var value = new Object();
        value.x = inputX;
        value.y = inputY;
        value.left = inputLeft;
        _values.push(value);

        x = inputX;
        y = inputY;
        left = inputLeft;
    }
    if (recordReset) {
        _values = []
    }
    if (play) {
        x = _values[_index] ? _values[_index].x : x;
        y = _values[_index] ? _values[_index].y : y;
        left = _values[_index] ? _values[_index].left : left;
        _index++;
    }
    if (playReset) {
        _index = 0;
    }

    result.outputX = x;
    result.outputY = y;
    result.outputLeft = left;   

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use QuickTime's screen recording to solve your problem

Comment: Don't ask questions in answers. Use comments for that. If you want to answer, then construct the sentence like, -->  *use QuickTime's screen recording to solve your problem*

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 50 reputation which allows me to comment. Sorry!

Comment: I have added the comment for you :-)

Comment: thanks! It would be good to be a bit more supportive for people who're not familiar to this community.

Comment: Yep, That's why I added a comment to warn you before hand. Welcome to Stack Overflow.